# Apache 2.2 <Location> errors: attempt to serve directory, no rewrites

Tags: apache-2.2

Setup: Apache 2.2 (Windows, win32).

httpd.conf snippets:

```
Alias /custom /var/www/custom

DirectoryIndex index.html

<Location /custom>
    SetHandler custom_handler
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</Location>

<Directory /var/www>
    Allow From all
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride all
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</Directory>
```

Also:

- mod_dir, mod_rewrite activated
- index.html present in /var/www/custom
- server process UID may read all files/directories in /var/www
- Apache service listens at all interfaces
- custom handler processes certain URLs within Location path, other are served from file system; index.html is processed as if no handler is present

Problems:

- rewriting URLs starting with the Location path are not working (no errors reported)
- when trying to serve http://server/custom (without closing slash), the following happens:

  - Apache redirects to http://ServerName/custom/ (to ServerName directive value)
  - "Attempt to serve directory" is written to error log for /var/www/custom/
  - 404 error is returned

How the above can be handled? The following is requried:

- serve /var/www/custom/index.html when http://server/custom is entered, or
- rewrite certain URLs, like

  > RewriteRule ^custom/$ /custom/index.html [L,R]

The above rewrite rule doesn't work, wherever it's placed (in or outside Location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing several different ways of mapping an URI to a part of the file system, and they don't all work together.

Firstly, if your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www`, then the AliasMap is completely unnecessary. This isn't clear from your snippet, though.

Second, since `/var/www/custom` is a directory, you should use the `Directory` directive when you refer to it. `Location` is used for things that aren't directories but that you would like to act as if they were.

To clear these points, try changing your config like this:

```
Alias /custom /var/www/custom  # ONLY if you don't have /var/www as DocumentRoot!

DirectoryIndex index.html

<Directory /var/www>
    Allow From all
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/custom>
    SetHandler custom_handler
</Directory>
```